# How to download a file from s3 using provided url?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

In my application I will get the url of s3 file like : https://s3.amazonaws.com/account-update/input.csv
I have to download it and then process it.
What I already done :

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
S3Object s3object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
bucketName, key));
```

I am able to download the file by providing bucket name and key, but how can I download the file using the url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/account-update/input.csv) only?

Answer (score 22):

You could download the file via a standard curl/wget, the same as you would download any other file off the Internet.

The important part, however, is to **enable access to the object** from Amazon S3. A few options:

- **Make the object publicly-readable:** This can be done via the console or CLI/API. However, anyone with that URL will be able to download it.
- **Create an [Amazon S3 Bucket Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)** that grants read access for the desired file/directory/bucket. But, again, anyone with the URL will be able to access those objects.
- Keep the object private, but **use a [pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)** that adds parameters to the URL to prove that you are permitted to download the object. This pre-signed URL is time-limited and can be generated with a few lines of code using current AWS credentials.

Comment: I saw examples using pre-signed URL for uploading objects. How can we generate pre-signed URL for downloading ?

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 22):

You may consider using the AWS SDK class [AmazonS3URI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3URI.html) as shown below:

```
URI fileToBeDownloaded = new URI(" https://s3.amazonaws.com/account-update/input.csv"); 

AmazonS3URI s3URI = new AmazonS3URI(fileToBeDownloaded);

S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(s3URI.getBucket(), s3URI.getKey());
```

From here on, you should be able to utilise the s3Object obtained in a similar fashion to the s3Object shown in your code.

For more Java related AWS SDK examples on using this class check [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3URI)

Comment: Is there something similar to AmazonS3URI in the newer SDK?  I'm using software.amazon.awssdk:s3.

Comment: Not yet available on AWS SDK V2. You may follow this [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/272)

Answer (score 3):

To enable access by HTTP, you must set the bucket up as a [Static Website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) in the S3 console. Be warned, this will expose all of your data to the web unless you set up proper [S3 access controls.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html)

The method you are accessing via the Java SDK will not use this type of connection, though. It will connect via the built-in S3 protocol. You should inspect your IAM Role or Policy to ensure you have the correct permissions (`s3:GetObject`). You will also need `s3:ListBucket` to see a 404 if the object does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using the pre-signed S3 URL to achieve your needs.
You can add expiration time to your signed URLs and after that the URL not available.

For more information read the following page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Answer (score 1):

Just enter the url on the browser but make sure to replace `\u0026` with `&` if you have downloaded the url via curl else you will get this error

> ```
> <Error>
>     <Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
>     <Message>X-Amz-Algorithm only supports "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"</Message>
> </Error>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**John Rotenstein** is correct, you can download the file via the URL using standard curl/wget.

If you wanted to do this using Java, something like the following should do the trick; making use of the [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) package

```
private void downloadRequest(String url, String savedFile) {
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            try (FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(savedFile)) {
                entity.writeTo(outstream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can make the file attachment in the upload.

For example:

```
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
objectMetadata.setContentType("application/csv;charset=utf-8");
objectMetadata.setContentDisposition("attachment");
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, arquivo, file, objectMetadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -5):

using cli: aws s3 cp s3://bucket/prefix/key targetlocalfolder

Comment: This question is about using a url with http, which does not work with the CLI the same way a regular s3 path does.